# What Kind of Command Will

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm looking for a command in python so whenever another different command is executed, it causes something else to happen. For example, something so that when

```
 turtle.dot()
```

is executed,

```
 turtle.pos()
```

happens. Maybe something like this?

```
if(turtle.dot()):
      turtle.pos(
```

But that doesn't seem to work.
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance,
C.

Comment: exactly what are you trying to do ? 
why do you need such thing.

Comment: Write a function that calls both, and use that instead.

Comment: What will you be using this for? Would it be possible to put what you're doing inside of a while loop? While(this): if(that):turtle.pos, or something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call one function after the other, from a helper function:

```
def something():
    turtle.dot()
    turtle.pos()
```

If the execution of `pos()` depends on the correct result of `dot()` then you're right on track:

```
def something():
    if turtle.dot() :
        turtle.pos()
```